# Animation In Android and Events

Tags: android

On my animation I have an event listener:

```
AnimationListener animationOutListener= new AnimationListener() {
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation fadeOutAnimation) {



        }}
```

How can I find out the view that the animation is taking place on?

Comment: With a single instance of an animation and a single instance of an AnimationListener, I don't believe there's a way to determine the View on which the Animation is operating. Is it practical for you to instead have separate instances of your Animation, each with its own Listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually the case that you have the target view when creating and attaching the animation listener to the animation since you have to afterwards start the animation by calling view.startAnimation(animation). If so - if you make your view final you'll have access to it from the anonymous class and you'll be able to use it in onAnimationEnd. If that's not the case you can use a setter for the target view to set it when starting the animation by calling view.startAnimation(animation)

```
public class CustomAnimationListener implements AnimationListener{


    private View mTarget;

    public void setTarget(final View target){
        mTarget = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        //use the target view here - mTarget
    }

    ...
}

animation.getAnimationListener().setTarget(view);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```